# Select all dataframe rows containing a specific integer

Tags: python, pandas

My data-frame looks something like this:

```
x    y 

1    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
1    g
```

All I want is to count the number of rows containing the number '1' in column 'x'. I know how this works for strings, but I can't find anything similar for numbers. The printed output in this case would be

```
3
```

Comment: Simple enough with `df.x.eq(1).sum()`

Comment: df['x'].value_counts().loc[1]

Comment: `df.x.value_counts()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.x == 1, 'x'].count()
```